# Read input different menu c#

Tags: c#, arrays, input, menu

Im trying to make a menu where an array will store input from a user (enterednumber 1) and then an admin can check the contents of the array in a different menu(enterednumber 9), but I can't seem to make it readable inside the admin menu.... I've left out the methods for login & startmenu, that part works. - the relevant part of the code currently looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int enteredNumber;

            int[] myArray = new int[10];

            Startmenu();
            enteredNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (enteredNumber == 1)
            {                    
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert Number:");
                    myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("blabla");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.Clear();
            }

            if (enteredNumber == 9)
            {
                if (Login(1234, 3) == true)
                {
                    foreach (int number in myArray)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(number);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: your myArray is declared **inside** the scope of the body of the *while* loop. This while loop is your actual menu loop. The thing is, with every iteration of the while loop, its formerly existing scope with all its variables and objects disappear (vanish from existence) unless those objects are referenced by some variable/field/whatever outside the while loop. And with each iteration of the loop the scope is reestablished again with a new fresh, empty myArray. Solution: Move the declaration of the array outside the while loop...

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` really?? LOL

Comment: I just set it to 1 quickly to test it without having to type in a million numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[10];

    while (true)
    {
        int enteredNumber;           
        // int[] myArray = new int[10]; //when you create a new int array , the array not contain values.
        Startmenu();
        enteredNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (enteredNumber == 1)
        {                    
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert Number:");
                myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("blabla");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
        }

        if (enteredNumber == 9)
        {
            if (Login(1234, 3) == true)
            {
                foreach (int number in myArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

when you create a new int array, the array contains no values, you have creation of an array within the while loop, then, int [] myArray = new int [10]; this empty when you start the cycle again, place the creation before starting the loop.